# php mt_rand generate numbers of x length with all zero's of said given length as well

Tags: php, string, random

I need to generate a string of numbers that are 20 digits long. Starting with 20 zeros ending with 20 nines. I can do this easily by running a normal `rand(0,9)` through a for loop.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++)
{
   $rng_salt .= rand(0,9);
}
```

But the loop is a lengthy process so to speak. I would like to try and figure out how to do this same thing with `mt_rand(00000000000000000000, 99999999999999999999)` or something similar. Preferably I'd like to do away with the loop and break it down to a single line if at all possible.

Comment: Just generate a number between those two and left pad 0s?

Comment: left pad? Right now doing the `mt_rand()` like Im doing I get a error about max something or another is smaller than min.

Comment: you referring to the `STR_PAD_LEFT` flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still have the whole loop in one line

```
for($i = 0, $rng_salt = ""; $i < 20; $i ++, $rng_salt .= mt_rand(0, 9));
var_dump($rng_salt);
```

You can also play around

```
$rng_salt = implode("",array_map(function($var){ return mt_rand(0, 9);}, range(0,19)));
var_dump($rng_salt);
```

What about doing some shuffle

```
$rng_salt = array_merge(range(0,9),range(0,9));
shuffle($rng_salt);
var_dump(implode("",$rng_salt));
```

Comment: Well I know I could break the loop into one line, but I want to do away with a looping process if at all possible.

Comment: well, ya definitely gave me plenty to work with. Ill see which works out better for my overall needs, thank you.

Comment: Just for reference. Not that I did any official kind of benchmarking for them. But Running the version with `shuffle` through a loop of 1000 and the one with `array_map`. The one that shuffles appears to generate and load a lot quicker than the others. Again thanks for the help, hopefully this question will also help others in the future

Comment: I would like to see the number @chris

Comment: It was a "stop watch" style test, where I generated an array with a 1000 runs of each, and did a var_dump on them there after, each type ran a few times. We are talking about fractions of a second, but overall again the keyword of it is, appears to be running faster :-)

Comment: @chris  you are right `shuffle` was faster that the rest .. See benchmark : http://codepad.viper-7.com/4VkFft

Answer (score 1):

Thinking outside the box here. Generate your random number for the range to the next decimal then simply trim off the first digit [1].

$rng_salt = substr(mt_rand(100000000000000000000, 199999999999999999999),1,20)

Check substr parameters. I could be off on the numbers.

Comment: This is a bit silly, you could just pad it, not to mention the OP is running into max number limits.

Comment: Yeah. Sure. You could just pad it too. It'll just add one more string manipulation step. Definitely better than a loop any day though.